# 2 messages produced to same partition one by one - message 1 overridden by next as kafka producer (0.8.2.1) returns same offset

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a unique problem which is happening like 50-100 times a day with message volume of ~2 millions per day on the topic.I am using Kafka producer API 0.8.2.1 and I have 12 brokers (v 0.8.2.2) running in prod with replication of 4. I have a topic with 60 partitions and I am calculating partition for all my messages and providing the value in the ProducerRecord itself. Now, the issue -

Application creates 'ProducerRecord' using -

```
new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, 30, null, message1);
```

providing topic, value *message1* and partition *30*. Then application call the send method and future is returned -

```
// null is for callback 
Future<RecordMetadata> future = producer.send(producerRecord. null);
```

Now, app prints the offset and partition value by calling get on Future and then getting values from RecordMetadata - this is what i get -

> Kafka Response :  partition 30, offset 3416092

Now, the app produce the next message - *message2* to same partition -

```
new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, 30, null, message2);
```

and kafka response -

> Kafka Response :  partition 30, offset 3416092

I receive the same offset again, and if I pull message from the offset of partition 30 using simple consumer, it ends up being the **message2** which essentially mean i **lost** the **message1**.

Based on KafkaProducer documentation [KafkaProducer](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html), I am using a single producer instance (static instance shared) among 10 threads.

> The producer is thread safe and should generally be shared among all threads for best performance.

I am using all default properties for producer (except max.request.size: 10000000), the message (String payload) size can be a few kbs to a 500 kbs. I am using ack value of 1.

What am i doing wrong here? Is there something I can look into or any producer property or server property I can tweak to make sure i don't lose any messages. I need some help here soon as I am losing some critical messages in production which is not good at all coz because of no exception its even hard to find out the message lost unless downstream process reports it.

**EDIT:**

> The servers and client are now updated to kafka version 0.8.2.2. Also, the 10 app threads each use their own instance of kafka producer now. We are seeing better performance but still there is message loss.

**Producer Properties:**

```
value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
bootstrap.servers: {SERVER VIP ENDPOINT}
acks: 1
batch.size: 204800
linger.ms: 10
send.buffer.bytes: 1048576
max.request.size: 10000000
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue locally ? If yes, then provide the code in a gist.

Comment: No I am not able to replicate issue in local, dev or even test environment. That is puzzling. I am not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: Since you used the default config, one possible reason behind the data loss is "request.required.acks" being 0, in which case, the producer does not wait for acknowledgement from the broker. You can set it to 1 and see that solves your data loss issue. This one has details: http://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html

Comment: @Salil, as i mentioned in question, i am already using the acks property plus with the new java producer in 0.8.2.2, default value for acks is 1 - http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#newproducerconfigs